# What is the geometric explanation for why the interior angles of a triangle sum to 180 degrees in both Euclidean space and Minkowski spacetime?

Tags: special-relativity, curvature, geometry

Four-dimensional Euclidean space has the same topology and affine structure as Minkowski spacetime, though the two have different metric structures.  Given that the interior angles of a triangle always sum to 180 degrees in both four-dimensional Euclidean space, and in Minkowski spacetime, is this fact due to both spaces having the same topology and/or affine structure, or is there some other explanation?

Comment: It's because neither of them is curved.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Right, but is the shared lack of curvature a primitive fact about both, or is there some further explanation?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166275

Comment: As I understand it, Minkowski spacetime  IS Euclidean space (with the addition of time), therefore the properties of Minkowski space, should be the same/apply in Euclidean space.